# How much is RDS for a small scale web app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

We have a 'small scale' web app. Actually just starting up. For devs already using RDS, how much (estimated) / month is it going to be for a small instance?

If possible, do share how much traffic and data is being used as well, so I can have a better picture of it all.

Second, we have another project: company profile web app (5 page layout). That lists down our products and services etc. We are expected to get moderate traffic. If we decide to run RDS on this, how much (estimated) will this cost us monthly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://aws.amazon.com/rds/, you have two options:

Point 1:

Different kind of services from small db instance to high level service

Point 2:

- dedicated instance
- on demand instance

What you have to know, from point 1:

- whatever instance you choose, you can create **has many databases as you want** on it

What you have to know, from point 2:

- For a normal web app, you'll have a permanent db running in the cloud so it's interesting to have a dedicated instance.

What it costs for a small db instance:

```
$227.50 /year + $0.046/hour * 24 hours/day * 365 days = $53/month
```

Don't forget you can do simulations [there](http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/calc5.html).

---

Sidenote:

I'm running 10 small websites on Heroku + a small RDS instance now. Queries are a bit long (which is normal) so:

- be sure to optimize them
- cache content whenever possible

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Very well placed.

Comment: I did 0.11 (small db instance per hour) * 24 (hours in a day) * 31 (days in a month) = 81.84. 0.100 (data transfer in per GB) * 20 (20 gb per month) = 2. 0.150 (data transfer out per TB) * 1 (tb per month) = 0.150. To sum it up: 81.84 + 2 + 0.150 = $83.99 / month. The simulation returns almost the same value at $84.22 / month for small db instance, 100% utilized, 20gb data transfer in and 20gb transfer out.

Comment: Just to give me an idea, how much data transfer in and out do some of your small web apps do per month?

Comment: I've 40Gb, for a mere additional $4